# Issues with stacking shipping containers at odd angles?

Tags: construction

We're interested in building a house out of intermodal shipping containers, probably the standard 40' x 8' x 8' ones.

I understand that (a) shipping containers were designed to be stacked on their corner castings with appropriate twistlock pins, and (b) their sides are important for the container's strength, but cannot support much themselves.

In particular, one maybe shouldn't stack them seven stories tall after you've cut nice big window in the sides, unless you've reinforced the windows properly.

I'm curious : What caveats apply to stacking containers diagonally?

I'm considering a two story design with a triangle of shipping containers that has a another triangle on top, almost like a star of David configuration, except there would be a gap between the containers on both levels.

In this design, the second story containers would rest not on the corner castings, but on the rails.  We'd cut only small windows in the bottom story, while cutting larger ones in the top story.

Comment: I would recommend talking to a residential structural engineer. Attempting to build a house with no experience and no knowledge of structure engineering is a bad idea.

Comment: Don't worry, we're quite a long ways from actually building anything, just curious.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you'd do better to support the upper level on columns/posts, rather than directly supporting on the containers below. I also suspect that you're engaged in fuzzy thinking if you think 3 40x8 foot boxes will make a nice triangle, unless you REALLY start messing with the structure. 90 degree ends don't make good 60 degree corners.

I think you'd likely be better off building from scratch if you want the shape you describe. It's not well-suited to shipping containers, and by the time you cobble things together to make it work with shipping containers, a ground-up build will probably be ahead, and far less compromised.